# Plugin para Visual Studio para criar region em javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

Olá,

Alguém conhece algum plugin para o Visual Studio para criar region em códigos javascript?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, o [Web Essentials for Visual Studio](http://vswebessentials.com/).

Use assim:

```
<!-- #region Regiao -->

@codigo

<!-- #endregion -->
```

Não sei se tem atalho pra criar *regions*, mas fica a dica.