# Como utilizar #region do C# no Javascript? (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: javascript, c#

Uso pouco para organizar meu código C#:

```
#region Nome
 //seu código
#endregion
```

Como posso fazer isso pelo javascript e Razor ?

```
@if()
{
  //code javascript
}
```

**Update:**

Conferi a resposta colega **Cigano Morrison Mendez** [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61232/54019) e não funcionou.

Baixei e instalei [Web Essentials 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebExtensionPack2017).

E nada acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei com [Advanced Javascript Outlining](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BenderBendingRodriguez.AdvancedJavaScriptoutlining) e não é compatível com visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encontrei a solução para JS:

**Obs:** **Só funciona com código JS. Não vai funcionar com Razor**.

[JavaScript Regions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.JavaScriptRegions).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Outra solução é utilizar atalho do Visual Studio:

1. Selecione o seu texto que você deseja.
2. Aperta <kbd>Ctrl + M</kbd> e <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Funcionou em uma IDE do jogo Screeps, vai que funciona para voce

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]